# ОШИБКА при установке yaml для Python

Tags: python, api, telegram, yaml

При установке yaml, командой:

$ `pip install pyyaml`

вылезает оповещение, что пакет установлен, а при запуске проекта:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'
```

как фиксануть?

Comment: Нужно убедиться, что модуль поставлен именно в тот интерпретатор, что используется в проекте. Возможно, у вас в проекте интерпретатор в виртуальном окружении, а при установке командой поставили в основной интерпретатор

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете проверить был ли установлен модуль командой:

```
$ pip freeze
```

Если модуль установлен, то требуется больше информации по вашей проблеме, например, показать код где вы его используете (импортируете).